# I can't add a script to facebook console?

Tags: javascript

While add this code to facebook console for example

```
$("body").hide();
```

It give me this error message

```
Uncaught Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","body"]]]>
    at h (qAxDeFGIZiE.js:41)
    at i (qAxDeFGIZiE.js:41)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

So Why .. ? and how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Judging by the error message, it is clear that `$` here is not referring to jQuery (because `$("body")` does not mean "element with id of `body`".)

Comment: if you try to use the same code in stackoverflow the `body` will hide !

Comment: Yes, because StackOverflow uses jQuery and Facebook does not. `$` is just a variable name and does not mean `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't use jQuery. Use vanilla JS.

`document.body.style.display = 'none';`